# BottomSheet - How to make it completely transparent - Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

How do I make a BottomSheetScaffold completely transparent?

I have a random white background showing up, even when I set the sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent.

Here's my BottomSheetScaffold

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red),
            scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
            sheetContent = {
                Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("Hello")
                }

            },
            sheetPeekHeight = 10.dp,
            sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        )
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to remove this white box inside the bottom sheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `sheetElevation` to `0.dp`.